# Why isn't CommonJS's require function asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

While loading CommonJS modules, we use `require` statement, which is synchronous. 
But doesn't loading modules involve reading them off the disk and interpreting them. So in a setup where we are advocating non blocking I/O how come `require`  is synchronous ?

**Update:**

I have seen and used requireJS in the client and can appreciate its asynchronous nature.  What I would like to know is that why doing something of this sort in the server is not widespread (I know requireJS can be used in Node but that is not the point).

Also I would like to know if requiring a module inline in my code makes my code blocking and if this is a bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Most generally, `require` is used for loading dependencies. And dependencies must be, well, present for their dependents to function.Hence synchronous load.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes but I can do something like : `require('crypto').createHash('md5').update(pwd+salt).digest("hex")` inline within a function body. Does it make my code blocking ?

Comment: @lorefnon The first time will be blocking, all subsequent ones will be served from a cache (but the node.js docu doesn't say how this exactly works). But why would you do this? Just require the crypto library at the top of your file like everyone else does.

Comment: Relevant: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

Comment: @Prinzhorn Thanks for the heads up on caching ... If you can post it as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require`ing modules is generally something you do at the beginning of your program. If you don't do it at the beginning of your program, the results are cached anyways. Starting a program like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var oranges = require('oranges');

// Do stuff
```

Would work the same as starting one like this:

```
require('async', function(err, async) {
    async.map(['fs', 'http', 'oranges'], function(err, modules) {
        var fs = modules[0], http = modules[1], oranges = modules[2];

        // Do stuff
    });
});
```

The difference is that one of them is needlessly complicated. Yes, there could be some kind of syntactic sugar implemented, but it still wouldn't have any benefit, except in maybe some tiny edge cases.